# Scala collection type for filter

Tags: scala, types, scala-2.8, scala-collections

Assume you have a List(1,"1") it is typed List[Any], which is of course correct and expected. Now if I map the list like this

```
scala> List(1, "1") map {
     |   case x: Int => x
     |   case y: String => y.toInt
     | }
```

the resulting type is List[Int] which is expected as well. My question is if there is an equivalent to map for filter because the following example will result in a List[Any]. Is this possible? I assume this could be solved at compile time and possibly not runtime?

```
scala> List(1, "1") filter {
     |   case x: Int => true
     |   case _ => false
     | }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Scala 2.9:

```
scala> List(1, "1") collect {
     |   case x: Int => x
     | }
res0: List[Int] = List(1)
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone stumbling across this question wondering why the most-voted answer doesn't work for them, be aware that the `partialMap` method was renamed `collect` before Scala 2.8's final release. Try this instead:

```
scala> List(1, "1") collect {
     |   case x: Int => x
     | }
res0: List[Int] = List(1)
```

(This should really be a comment on Daniel C. Sobral's otherwise-wonderful answer, but as a new user, I'm not allowed to comment yet.)

Answer (score 1):

With regard to your modified question, if you simply use a guard in the case comprising your partialFunction, you get filtering:

```
scala> val l1 = List(1, 2, "three", 4, 5, true, 6)
l1: List[Any] = List(1, 2, three, 4, 5, true, 6)

scala> l1.partialMap { case i: Int if i % 2 == 0 => i }
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 4, 6)
```

Comment: Why is this only possible with a guard?

Comment: Sorry, that was a really stupid comment. But why is filter() not generating a result like partialMap?

Comment: @Joa `filter` does not change the type of a collection, because it does not modify its elements.

Comment: Well, filter just takes a predicate, which gives the compiler nothing to go on for inferring the result type. Whereas with a partial function, it can use the types of the results of all the cases and compute an upper bound on those types as the overall type of the partial function.