# Scala collection filter by type

Tags: scala, types, filter, scala-collections, type-erasure

im new to scala and ran into the following problem:

I want to get a subcollection of an existing collection that only contains elements of a specific type. The following works:

```
class C(val name : String)
class D(name : String) extends C(name) { }

val collection = Set[C](new C("C1"),new D("D1"),new C("C2"),new D("D2"))
collection.collect{case d : D => d}.size must be === 2 // works
```

But when i try to extend the collection classes with a method "onlyInstancesOf[Type]" this does not work. First my implementation:

```
object Collection {
    implicit def extendScalaCollection[E](coll : Traversable[E]) = new CollectionExtension[E](coll)
}

class CollectionExtension[E](coll : Traversable[E]) {

    def onlyInstancesOf[SpecialE <: E] : Traversable[SpecialE] = {
        coll.collect({case special : SpecialE => special}).asInstanceOf[Traversable[SpecialE]]
    }
}
```

So when i use this extension and execute:

```
collection.onlyInstancesOf[D].size must be === 2
```

I get an error that .size returned 4 and not 2. Also, i checked, the result actually contains C1 and C2 though it should not.

When i do:

```
collection.onlyInstancesOf[D].foreach(e => println(e.name))
```

I get the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: CollectionsSpec$$anonfun$1$C$1 cannot be cast to CollectionsSpec$$anonfun$1$D$1
```

So obviously the resulting set still contains the elements that should have been filtered out.

I dont get why this happens, can anyone explain this?

Edit: 
Scala: Scala code runner version 2.8.0.final

Comment: Doesn't this code generate a warning?

Comment: You are right, but as it turned out the warning was not shown while testing because the file was compiled some time ago and did not get recompiled :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala collection type for filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218558/scala-collection-type-for-filter)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pay attention to the compiler warnings, and add -unchecked your scala command line options.

```
M:\>scala -unchecked
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.final (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_21)
.
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class CollectionExtension[E](coll : Traversable[E]) {
     |
     |     def onlyInstancesOf[SpecialE <: E] : Traversable[SpecialE] = {
     |         coll.collect({case special : SpecialE => special}).asInstanceOf[Traversable[SpecialE]]
     |     }
     | }
<console>:8: warning: abstract type SpecialE in type pattern SpecialE is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
               coll.collect({case special : SpecialE => special}).asInstanceOf[Traversable[SpecialE]]
                                            ^
defined class CollectionExtension
```

The warning means that the best the compiler can do is equivalent to:

```
coll.collect({case special : AnyRef => special}).asInstanceOf[Traversable[_]]
```

For a more detailed explanation of type erasure, and ways you can work around it with Manifests, see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-erasure+scala

Answer (score 6):

As others have pointed out, manifests can rescue you.  Here's an example of how, restricting ourselves to non-primitives, and assuming we don't want to store manifests in our collections but instead use reflection on the spot to figure things out:

```
class CollectionExtension[E <: AnyRef](coll : Traversable[E]) {
  def onlyInstancesOf[SpecialE <: E](implicit mf : Manifest[SpecialE]) : Traversable[SpecialE] = {
    coll.collect({
      case special if mf.erasure.isAssignableFrom(special.getClass) => special
    }).asInstanceOf[Traversable[SpecialE]]
  }
}
```

and here it is in action:

```
scala> val ce = new CollectionExtension(List(Some(1),Some(5),"This","Fox")) 
ce: CollectionExtension[java.lang.Object] = CollectionExtension@1b3d4787

scala> val opts = ce.onlyInstancesOf[Some[_]]
opts: Traversable[Some[_]] = List(Some(1), Some(5))

scala> val strings = ce.onlyInstancesOf[String] 
strings: Traversable[String] = List(This, Fox)
```

Answer (score 5):

Scala runs on the JVM, which unfortunately erases type parameters at runtime: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure. In your first example, you give the type in a non-erased position and so the runtime code can do the comparison. In the second example, the `SpecialE` type is erased, and hence the code will return everything.

You can use scala's Manifests to regain some of the information lost by type erasure:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassManifest
class CollectionsExtension[E <: AnyRef](coll : Traversable[E]) {
  def onlyInstancesOf[SpecialE <: E](implicit m : Manifest[SpecialE]) : Traversable[SpecialE] = {
    coll.collect({case e if (ClassManifest.singleType(e) <:< m) => e}).asInstanceOf[Traversable[SpecialE]]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As the warning say:

```
<console>:14: warning: abstract type SpecialE in type pattern SpecialE is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
               coll.collect({case special : SpecialE => special}).asInstanceOf[Traversable[SpecialE]]
```

Let's see the implementation of `collect`:

```
def collect[B, That](pf: PartialFunction[A, B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, That]): That = {
  val b = bf(repr)
  for (x <- this) if (pf.isDefinedAt(x)) b += pf(x)
  b.result
}
```

Note that there's no pattern matching in here. This is the fundamental difference -- when you write "`collection.collect{case d : D => d}`" the compiler knows exactly what type you are talking about: `D`.

On the other hand, when you write `coll.collect({case special : SpecialE => special})`, the compiler doesn't know what type `SpecialE`, because `SpecialE` is just a type parameter. So it can't generate code that knows what `SpecialE` is, and, at run-time, there's no `SpecialE` anymore -- the bytecode just uses `java.lang.Object`.